# Set time for the screen to stay on

Tags: android, power-management, wakelock

I already know where to begin, at least by WakeLock class, but I can only call methods on and off the screen ... I do not know the simplest way to terminate a while for the screen to begin start off .. (brightness decreases slightly before turning off completely).

Thank you! I hope I have expressed myself right.

Comment: You can try with `System` class, I believe there's a value to set the current birghtness. Maybe with a count down timer.

Comment: I serached into the docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html) but could not find anything about brightness setting or something on the screen

Comment: ther's an api to retrieve the screen timeout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT but android don't let you know the 'Dimming' timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

I used the SCREEN_OF_TIMEOUT method for the system class.
Here is the code:

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 60000);
```

The number 60000 refers the time to the screen timeout (in ms).
Thanks!